# C# JSON String returned in ambiguous format

Tags: javascript, c#, json

i have an issue with my logged Json String as it replaces the double quotes with `&quot;`

Controller  Code :

```
var message = new SuccessMessagesVM()
        {
            Title = successMessageType == (int)EnumHelper.SuccessMessageTypes.Add ? "It's beautiful" : CustomModel.Resources.SuccessMessagesResources.EditFormSuccess,
            Message = successMessageType == (int)EnumHelper.SuccessMessageTypes.Add ? CustomModel.Resources.SuccessMessagesResources.AddFormSuccess : CustomModel.Resources.SuccessMessagesResources.EditFormSuccess,
            ColorCode = (int)EnumHelper.MessagesCodes.Success
        };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
        ViewBag.SuccessMessage = successMessageType == 0 ? null : json;
```

Javascript just logs the `ViewBag.SuccessMessage` as following:

```
console.log('@ViewBag.SuccessMessage');
```

and the object is displayed as `{&quot;Message&quot;:&quot;تم إضافة النموذج بنجاح&quot;,&quot;Title&quot;:&quot;It&#39;s beautiful&quot;,&quot;ColorCode&quot;:3}`
replacing all single quotes with `&#39;` and all double quotes with `&quot;`

I expect the output to be `{"Message":"تم إضافة النموذج بنجاح","Title":"It's beautiful","ColorCode":3}`

Comment: The solution, to use `@Html.Raw()` will be the same, regardless; but have you considered using a model for your data?  This way, you don't have to serialize it to/from JSON.  It might be much cleaner for you this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using `ViewBag` variable.

In order to use `ViewBag`, you can write it as followed:

First, in view:

```
@{
        var jss = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        var successMessageJson = jss.Serialize(ViewBag.SuccessMessage);
}
```

Then use it:

```
<script>
    //use Json.parse to convert string to Json
    var successMessageInfo = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(successMessageJson)');
</script>
```

Comment: +1 But this behavior is not specific to ViewBag.  When using TempData, ViewData or Model, you would still need to use @Html.Raw in order to return the data as HTML.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few different issues and a few different approaches, and the OP doesn't give us any view code, so it's a bit of guesswork.

My feeling is that you should just return the `SuccessMessagesVM` from your method, and access the properties individually in your view (probably using @Html.DisplayFor and HTML). This will ensure that any redundant quotation marks are never created in the first place, and will give you total control over how the values are displayed.

You should not expect `console.log(@ViewBag.Anything)` to display properly. If you need the data as a JavaScript object, don't stick it in the ViewBag, as it will get rendered as HTML.

If you must write to a JavaScript object you can, but it begs the question why are you not using an ajax request if all you want is data?